# Change terminal password echo character

Tags: sudo

On arch linux, when I use sudo, how can I echo password characters as  `●`  instead of  `*`  ?

I have `nerd-fonts` installed, and I am using `alacritty` as my **terminal emulator**.

I already modified the sudoers file using visudo, and enabled echo character using

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

Comment: I suspect (but don't know) you won't be able to without changing the `sudo` executable's source and recompiling. Not only is this unlikely to be user-configurable since it is so minor, you are asking it to support non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @terdon I'd agree, on the other hand, my sudo doesn't show *anything* for typed in characters, so my guess is that this is already some `askpass` compatible program, but that's a wild guess!

Answer (score 1):

In `sudo`'s own password input routine, [`*` is hard coded](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/SUDO_1_9_13p3/src/tgetpass.c#L416), but you can also get `sudo` to use an external command to input the password, including graphical ones like `ssh-askpass`, `/usr/libexec/seahorse/ssh-askpass` or implement your own.

Now also note that while `*` is part of the ASCII set and should be invariant across all locales on your system, `●` is not and is found in very few character sets and its encoding varies with the locale. In UTF-8, it's encoded on 3 bytes, so you'd need a routine that can cope OK with multibyte characters, and can encode that `●` OK in the user's locale and fall back to some other character when the locale doesn't have such a character.

For instance, you could write one as:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Term::ReadPassword;
use Encode::Locale;
use Encode;

$Term::ReadPassword::USE_STARS = 1;
my $bullet = encode(locale => "\N{BLACK CIRCLE}");
$Term::ReadPassword::STAR_STRING = $bullet eq '?' ? '*' : $bullet;

$pass = read_password(join " ", @ARGV);
if (defined($pass)) {
  print "$pass\n";
} else {
  exit(1);
}
```

Run `export SUDO_ASKPASS=/path/to/that-script` or add `Path askpass /path/to/that-script` to `/etc/sudo.conf` and run `sudo` with `-A`:

```
$ sudo -A id -u
[sudo] password for you: ●●●●●●●●●●●●●●
0
```

Note that AFAIK, Term::ReadPassword is not multibyte aware. If you enter a multibyte character at that prompt, as many bullets as there are bytes in the character will be displayed. It should still work OK though.